# Cómo obtener los params de peticiónes Http en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, http, postman

Buen día comunidad, estoy tratando de obtener los Params de una peticion Http enviada desde Postman pero no llega

[image: Petición PostMan]

He intentado con:

```
$request->query();
```

Pero no llega nada

Comment: cómo estás comprobando el valor de `$request->query()`?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de `$request->query();` debes especificar el nombre de la key, en tu caso sería **codpro**. Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
@php
    $param = request()->query('codpro');

@endphp
{{$param}}
```

Comment: Sí probé de esa y muchas maneras, pero al final encontré el error. Tenía que ver con el Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

El error tenía que ver con el NGINX y esto no permitía al Laravel recibir parámetros, en el archivo config se agregó $query_string; y ya empezó a recibirlos

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        
    }
```